# C# ReportViewer and data from several databases

Tags: c#, windows, database, reportviewer

I'm trying to make a report which will be able to receive data from a DB I'm currently connected to.

The problem is that when I'm creating the report using the wizard or just putting in it a table, it requires a dataset and then I have to choose a specific DB, therefore it will not be able to get data from another database.

I also noticed that I can give it a ReportDataSource which gets a dataTable, but I don't understand how  it would put in the data (to which textboxes?) or how I tell it how to do it. Anyway, even so I get an error that tells me that the report doesn't have a dataset and again pops the first problem.

Does anybody know how I can do this or have a link? examples? anything???
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report designer and report wizard in VS are trying to be a little too smart for you. There is a simple workaround involving a dummy dataset. It lets you take full advantage of the report designer and still hook up to a different DB at runtime. It's not ideal, but it does work. I've outlined that approach [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/magreer/archive/2008/10/16/setting-the-datasource-for-a-report-at-runtime.aspx).